# toggle style on current class elem when clicked in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
  var expandIt=document.getElementsByClassName('k-grid');  

  function expandClickcurrentNOTs () { 
      console.log('pressed'); // works
      console.log(e.target); // but need to add class to only class elem clicked
    }

  for (i = 0; i < expandIt.length; i++) {
    expandIt[i].addEventListener("click", expandClickcurrentNOTs);
  }
```

Above is what I have; I simply want to add a style when one of my class elements is clicked.. But only to that specific one, not all other class elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the elements using [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), which returns a static [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) the you can iterate with `NodeList.forEach()`. Add an event handler to each element, and in the handler use toggle to add/remove the class name from the element's [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```js
const expandIt = document.querySelectorAll('.k-grid')
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.classList.toggle('pressed')
  }))
```

```css
.k-grid.pressed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="k-grid">k-grid</div>
<div class="k-grid">k-grid</div>
<div class="k-grid">k-grid</div>
<div class="k-grid">k-grid</div>
<div class="k-grid">k-grid</div>
<div class="k-grid">k-grid</div>
```